# Does the order of a Numpy array matter for CNN classification?

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, multidimensional-array

Image classification of RGB images in a Convolutional Neural Network is usually done by feeding the CNN first layer with a Numpy array with dimensions: pixel array by the number of channels. Example: [256 pixels] x [256 pixels] x [3 channels].

What is the impact on performance if applying a different Numpy array in a different order: say [256 pixels] x [3 channels] x [256 pixels], assuming that the CNN first layer structure is changed?

1. Does the CNN architecture of the sub-sequent layers need to be changed?
2. Would the model prediction accuracy be impacted?

My use case is a bit different where I have multiple features in a Numpy Array [ [X pixels],[Y pixels],[RGB channels],[ABC channels],[EF channels] ] and I'm concerned that the order of how the features are entered into the CNN will impact the model training.

Comment: when you construct and train the net, this learn features For the order combination you proposed. changing dimensions will cause an error (if swaped dimensions has different sizes) or just work bad.
In the case where swap dimensions in training (if it does not cause error by sizes) the net could "learn" to be robust against this. But the most likely outcome is a net with lower performance

Comment: I agree with Ulises. You should probably reformat all of your data to match some predefined input shape. In tensorflow specifically, as long as the order of the channels is consistent for all of the input data, it won't matter what that order actually is (for instance BGR or RGB). I can't speak for pytorch or other libraries. Finally, I don't think that inserting the channels dimension in axis 1 (e.g. 256x3x256) makes sense. It is unnecessary and will complicate your network for no reason. I would stick to 3x256x256 or 256x256x3. This works especially well with tensorflow's conv2D function.